# Binding mouse cursor to button property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a button that takes a lot fo time to finish its function and it seems that the application has stopped because of the long wait (5 seconds). So before the long running function I put `Cursor = Cursors.Wait` and after the function I put `Cursor = Cursors.Arrow`and everything worked.

But I think that's a really awful way to do such a thing.

That's why I'd like to know if it's possible to bind the cursor to a button's property so that the cursor will change while the button is performing its functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, six years later.
1. Look at async-await construction, it's easy and your hard task wiil execute in non-UI thread.
2. Since you step through previous one you may put some bool property into your model like `actionExecuting` and set/unset it before/after your task done. Then in view you can bind a `Cursor` property of your main container to `actionExecuting`. To make the trick you need an implementation of `IValueConverter`. For example (take a look to namespace):

```
namespace YourApp.Util.Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Cursor))]
    public class BoolToCursorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var val = (bool)value;
            if (val)
                return Cursors.WaitCursor;
            return Cursors.Arrow;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you're to add this converter to view in the `Window.Resources` or in your resource dictionary like:

```
<Window x:Class="YourApp.MainWindow"
        <!-- other namespaces -->
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:YourApp.Util.Converters">

<Window.Resources>
        <c:BoolToCursorConverter x:Key="BoolToCursorConverter"></c:BoolToCursorConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And than you can use it like

```
<Grid Cursor="{Binding actionExecuting, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCursorConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't u use a background worker for a long running function (maybe produce/consumer pattern)? in my opinion that's the best way. you could also inform the user with a progress bar about the status of his request.

Comment: I've thought about using threads, but it's not just one button. There are many like that. Wouldn't it actually be the same as putting those 2 lines of code before and after the functions ended?

Comment: without any further informations about your program i'm not able to give you a satisfactory answer. but maybe you could'd use thread-pool for that problem.

Comment: I'll look into that. But do you know if there's a way to bind the cursor property to the button.isfocused property (for example)? I think that I can't do that to the cursor since it's not a dependencyobject

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing I can think of is to create a class that implements IDisposable and change the wait cursor in the constructor, and revert it back in the Dispose method. that ensures that if an exception is thrown while the code it wraps is executing, the cursor won't get stuck as a wait cursor...

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private Cursor m_defaultCursor = null;
    public WaitCursor()
    {
        m_defaultCursor = Cursors.Current;
        Cursors.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cursors.Current = m_defaultCursor;
        Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
    }
}
```

and then you can just wrap your long running code with using statements...

```
using (var waitCursor = new WaitCursor())
{
    // some long running code...
}
```

that sort of makes it clear to future developers that the wrapped code probably takes a while too

Answer (score 0):

You can in theory create a dependency property somewhere which sets the mouse cursor whenever the button state changes. But it's not likely to do anything if you do are doing work inside of the button click handler, since your UI thread needs to be dispatching for dependency objects to update. Also, you won't see your button visually 'unpress' until the task completes if you are blocking the UI thread. Also, how would you bind it to an open, maybe changing set of buttons? It doesn't sound like a satisfactory solution.

I think the best way to handle such scenarios in WPF apps is to run long-running tasks in a background thread (or thread pool), which will post its results back to the UI thread when it is finished. While this happens, in the meantime you can either keep the UI fully interactive, or go with the wait cursor (and explicitly disable your UI), or block it with a dialog saying 'work in progress, please wait [Cancel button]' if you feel like giving a cancel option.

Doing things in a background thread is also good for keeping your WPF application window responsive to window management actions like move/minimize/maximize.